# - Default value of variables at the time of declaration -

Tags: iphone, variables, initialization, declaration, header-files

I was wondering what were the default values of variables before I initialized them...

For example, if I do :

```
//myClass.h

BOOL myBOOL; // default value ?
NSArray *myArray; // default value ?
NSUInteger myInteger; // default value ?
```

Some more examples here :

```
//myClass.m
// myArray is not initialized, only declared in .h file

if ([myArray count] == 0) { // TRUE or FALSE ?

// do whatever

}
```

More generally, what is returned when I do :

```
[myObjectOnlyDeclaredAndNotInitialized myCustomFunction];
```

Thank you for your answers.

Gotye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on the scope in which the variable is defined.

Instance variables of Objective-C objects are always initialised to 0/nil/false because the memory allocated is zeroed.

Global variables are *probably* initialised to 0/nil/false to because when memory is first allocated to a process, it is also zeroed by the operating system. However, as a matter of course, I never rely on that and always initialise them myself.

Local variables are uninitialised and will contain random data depending on how the stack has grown/shrunk.

NB for pointers to Objective-C objects, you can safely send messages to nil.  So, for instance:

```
NSArray* foo = nil;
NSLog(@"%@ count = %d", foo, [foo count]);
```

is perfectly legal and will run without crashing with output something like:

```
2010-04-14 11:54:15.226 foo[17980:a0f] (null) count = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

by default NSArray value will be nil , if you would not initialize it.

Comment: would you have any source ? Cheers ;)

Comment: i face that type of problem before.
thats why i can told you that the default value for NSArray will be nil...

Answer (score 0):

```
//myClass.h

BOOL myBOOL; // default value ?
NSArray *myArray; // default value ?
NSUInteger myInteger; // default value ?
```

the Bool myBool if not initialized will receive the default value of False.

NSArray *myArray if not allocated,initialized(for example `NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc]  init];`) will have the default value of NIL. if you call count on an unitialized array you will receive an exception not 0.

```
//myClass.m
// myArray is not initialized, only declared in .h file

if ([myArray count] == 0) { => here it should crash because of [myArray count]

// do whatever

}
```

for the NSUInteger myInteger the default value should be 0, the documentation says that this is used to describe an unsigned integer(i didn;t represent integers with this one though)

when you call `[myObjectOnlyDeclaredAndNotInitialized myCustomFunction];` it should break, throw an exception.

hope it helps

Comment: Wrong answer, from my experience, myArray not initialized implies that myArray == nil. Passing any message to nil will return nil.